# ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, lstm

I try to create model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, input_shape=X_train.shape))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

but when i try to run it `model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=1)` throws

> `ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2`

[full code](https://pastebin.com/ZR9DaBvM)

[data file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/biyczttoqj7b8qq/data.txt?dl=0)

[data format](https://pastebin.com/GKaBHtL9)

Thanks!

PS. I know about other questions, but they didn`t help me.

Comment: can you try changing input_shape to `(None, X_train.shape)`

Comment: @UpasanaMittal [not works](https://pastebin.com/SLr4ttri)

Comment: @UpasanaMittal `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (34, 1)`

Comment: Ok. Looks like error need to be reproduced. Will do it.